# Why is this https URL can't be queried with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

I have a bunch of web services I have to call, all in **https**, and only one is not working, got a SSL error

> Error: write EPROTO 12632:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:openssl\ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1407:SSL alert number 40

I'm using **node version 10.13.0**.
I tried to force the protocol with a
`https.globalAgent.options.secureProtocol = "TLSv1_method"`
with no luck.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious but I must confess I'm a bit lost here :/

```
const https = require('https');

const url= "https://rec-www.calvados.fr";
const urlOptions= {};
const data= "";

const resolve= (o)=> {
    console.log("resolve", o);
}
const reject= (o)=> {
    console.log("reject", o);
}

const req= https.request(url, urlOptions, res => {
    let body= "";
    res.on("data", chunk => (body += chunk.toString()));
    res.on("error", reject);
    res.on("end", () => {

        if(res.statusCode && res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode <= 299) {
            resolve({statusCode: res.statusCode, headers: res.headers, body});
        } else {
            reject("Request failed. status: " + res.statusCode + ", body: " + body);
        }
    });
});
req.on("error", reject);
req.write(data, "binary");
req.end();
```

Change the URL with another one to see it working. But with that one, boom....

Any ideas ?

Cheers.

**--updated--**

To follow @antonku's answer, here is what I got from:
    **openssl s_client -connect rec-www.calvados.fr:443**

```
CONNECTED(000001E8)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=FR/postalCode=14035/ST=Calvados/L=CAEN/street=B.P. 12/street=12, rue Saint-Laurent/street=Conseil g\xC3\xA9n\xC3\xA9ral/O=DEPARTEMENT DU CALVADOS/OU=0002 221401185/CN=*.calvados.fr

   i:/C=FR/ST=Calvados/L=Caen/O=TBS INTERNET/OU=TBS INTERNET CA/CN=TBS X509 CA business 2
 1 s:/C=FR/ST=Calvados/L=Caen/O=TBS INTERNET/OU=TBS INTERNET CA/CN=TBS X509 CA business 2
   i:/C=US/ST=New Jersey/L=Jersey City/O=The USERTRUST Network/CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=US/ST=New Jersey/L=Jersey City/O=The USERTRUST Network/CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=FR/postalCode=14035/ST=Calvados/L=CAEN/street=B.P. 12/street=12, rue Saint-Laurent/street=Conseil g\xC3\xA9n\xC3\xA9ral/O=DEPARTEMENT DU CALVADOS/OU=0002 221401185/CN=*.calvados.fr
issuer=/C=FR/ST=Calvados/L=Caen/O=TBS INTERNET/OU=TBS INTERNET CA/CN=TBS X509 CA business 2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 4558 bytes and written 626 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DES-CBC3-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DES-CBC3-SHA
    Session-ID: D67EB3B87B19B41B353B66E4CC57B1DD4611E626C6BE6FFB173053B4B25C80A0
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: CB98E88373100902EB194E8E555A9991D001B55806408546E28C1C8733E700B45B5EECC8BAC5CC27C66309277C38B296
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1546955507
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

Could the last line the culprit ?

Comment: isn't your `req.end()` occuring too early ? because in your code, `req.end()` happens before the response is received... I would `end` it in your `resolve` and `reject` functions.

Comment: @dun32: I believe the req.end() is just saying that I have nothing more to say but not that I'm closing/killing the connection. It's useful for the http server in order to know that I'm finish and that it can start to send an answer.
Thanx anyway for your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to setup `https` connection, the server `rec-www.calvados.fr` is pointed to, needs to have an SSL certificate installed. As I can see, at the moment, the server does not return any SSL certificates in response, that's why the connection fails.

Should you want to use a secure connection (`https`), it's required to configure an SSL certificate on the server side.
Alternatively, if the secrecy is not important, you can go with plain insecure `http` instead of `https`.

Comment: Looks like you're on something ;)
I've check the SSL certificate with this:
`https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=rec-www.calvados.fr`
Got a
`No SSL certificates were found on rec-www.calvados.fr. Make sure that the name resolves to the correct server and that the SSL port (default is 443) is open on your server's firewall.`

Comment: I've updated the question to display openssl view. Just to be sure this is the source of the problem. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That's interesting, the openssl output that your have shared shows the certificate. However when I run the same openssl command, I don't see any certificates in response. Can it be the case that the domain name `rec-www.calvados.fr` resolves to different IP addresses on your and my sides? My dns query for `rec-www.calvados.fr` returns `62.39.115.180` for the A record. Can you please check to which IP address it resolves on your machine?

Comment: Same IP from here I'm afraid..... This thing is definitively weird. But as other clients are able to connect to this website (either the browser or wget/curl), I'm guessing there is something in the node conf I'm not doing while I should.

Comment: I see, well, I have noticed one more thing, the certificate seems to be installed, but the server appears to support only a single cipher suite according to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=rec-www.calvados.fr&hideResults=on which is `TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA`. It's quite possible that the node.js instance where the error occurs does not support it, so that I think it makes sense to check if the aforementioned cipher suite is supported by the node.js instance.

Comment: I tried setting it specifically or setting to ALL. No success.
And I saw this [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103992/tls-rsa-with-3des-ede-cbc-sha-reported-as-112-bits). So maybe this cipher is not allowed anymore with node.... Anyway, I will try to contact the client. For now, let's close it. But if you have any more idea on how to config https with node, feel free to barge in ;) Kudos to you, Anton

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer :). You can find all cipher suites supported by node.js instance by executing `require('tls').getCiphers()`. In this way you can check if the only cipher suite supported by the server is in the list. However, in my opinion, this definitely needs to be fixed by modifying SSL/TLS configuration on the server side, since allowing only one weak cipher suite over a pretty old TLS version is a security issue that should be addressed.